# need help to start puzzle game

Tags: iphone

i am new to gaming programing.

i am trying to develop a simple puzzle game.

for that i need to crop a original image into 9 pieces [like this](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b1310d64ab.jpg).

i am getting confusion how can i crop image in to pieces,

how to exchange image to each other when one image is comes over the another image.

is there any sample code or tutorial regarding this puzzle game

can any one please post it.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: You can do the trick if you want , just add the imageview of that size on whole screen , if you want i can send code for same image

Comment: defiantly GhostRider your are... please post code

Answer (score 0):

You can download the sample project here:

http://shmoopi.net/Slider%20Puzzle%202.zip

https://github.com/ixnixnixn/IXNTilePuzzle